# Java execute .exe file

Tags: java

I want to execute a .exe file i made from C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void helloFromC(){
    printf("Hello from C!");
}

int main(){
 helloFromC();
 return 0;
}
```

Currently this is what i am trying but it gives me `Error: Could not find or load main class Test` (which is the class i am currently using in Java):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filename = "D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Testing\\TestFile.exe";
            Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = rTime.exec(filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the java class?

Comment: I am running it in Eclipse

Comment: Try to run in command line.

Comment: Looks like your class is not compiled or that is in a wrong location.

Comment: how are you compiling and running the code? is the path to the file Test.class ok while using javac?

Comment: how are you running it in eclipse

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I managed to fix it . I deleted the whole project dir and created a new one. Seems to work now.

Comment: Well that's not a very good solution... Imagine one day it happens to you while you are working on a 6 GB project. You should better understand your IDE

Comment: I think that the problem was that i delete the project just from eclipse while the directory still existed in my computer. Then i created a project with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Your questoin already been answered in Stackoverflow.

[Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

You can execute executable using ProcessBuilder class in Java.

**Without Parameters:**

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ExecutablePath\\TestExe.exe").start();
```

**With Parameters:**

Pass your arguments in constructor itself.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ExecutablePath\\TestExe.exe","param1","param2").start();
```